# better way of using reduceLeft/foldLeft on list of case class

Tags: scala

My intention is simple: to get comma seperated values of emaild from list of User objects.
I have done this in Java with a for loop and if else conditions.

Now i want to do it in Scala, so i tried this.

```
case class User(name: String, email: String)

val userList = List(User("aaa", "aaa@aaa.com"),
                    User("bbb", "bbb@bbb.com"),
                    User("ccc", "ccc@ccc.com"))
```

now

```
val mailIds = userList.foldLeft(""){(a: String, b: User) => ( b.email+","+a) }
```

gives

```
ccc@ccc.com,bbb@bbb.com,aaa@aaa.com,
```

(note the comma at the end.)

and

```
val mailids = userList.map(x => x.email).reduceLeft(_+","+_)
```

gives

```
aaa@aaa.com,bbb@bbb.com,ccc@ccc.com
```

i tried using only `reduceLeft` like this

```
val emailids = userList.reduceLeft((emails: String, user: User) => emails+", "+user.email)
```

but it throws compilation error

```
type mismatch;  found   : (String, User) => java.lang.String  required: (java.io.Serializable, User) => java.io.Serializable
```

so, is there a **better** way of using `reduceLeft` without `map` in the above case ?

Comment: The "best" way is to use `mkString`: `userList.map(_.email).mkString(",")`.

Comment: +1. Travis, excellent suggestion. put this in the answers please

Comment: Thanks, Rajesh, but my comment doesn't really answer your question as posed.

Comment: in a way it does, it makes the code as simple as possible at the same time readable and easily understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `reduceLeft` is a `foldLeft` where the accumulator is the first element of the collection. In your case this first element is a `User` and you have to pass an argument of the same type for the next step of the iteration. That is why you get a type missmatch. 

You can do the map within a lazy collection and reduce this like the following:

```
val mailIds = userList.view map (_.email) reduceLeft (_ + "," + _)
```

This will give you `aaa@aaa.com,bbb@bbb.com,ccc@ccc.com` without creating a second collection. Jessie Eichar wrote a verry good [tutorial](http://daily-scala.blogspot.de/2009/11/non-strict-lazy-collections.html) for that.

**EDIT**

A way without a lazy collection would be deleting the last comma by:

```
val rawMailIds = userList.foldLeft("")((acc, elem) => acc + elem.email + ",")
val mailIds = rawMailIds.substring(0, rawMailIds.length - 1)
```

Comment: Or `val mailIds = userList.tail.foldLeft(userList.head.email){(a: String, b: User) => ( b.email+","+a) }` (assumes userList is non-empty)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you stick with the combination of map and reduce? In any case, your issue is that your `reduceLeft` only version needs to have a string as its initial value.

Comment: I think he doesn't want another collection to be produced while computing the String.